# Why is the program printing 0s?

Tags: c, arrays

I've gone over the code and re-written it several times already and each time I get 0s when printing the array and the mean. I'm using codeblocks as the ide.

Below is statlib.c

```
// Calculates the mean of the array
double calculateMean(int totnum, double data[ ])
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    int i;

    // adds elements in the array one by one
    for(i = 0; i < totnum; i++ )
        sum += data[i];

    average = (sum/totnum);

return average;
}// end function calculateMean
```

Below is the other file

```
#include "statlib.c"
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){

    int i; // counter used in printing unsorted array
    double mean = 0.0;
    double data[10] = {30.0,90.0,100.0,84.0,72.0,40.0,34.0,91.0,80.0,62.0};         // test data given in assignment
    int totnum = 10; // total numbers in array


//Print the unsorted array
printf("The unsorted array is: {");
    for ( i = 0; i < totnum; i++){
        printf(" %lf",data[i]);
        printf(",");
    }
    printf("}\n");

//Get and display the mean of the array
    mean = calculateMean(totnum,data);
    printf("The mean is: %lf\n",mean);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: At a brief glance, your code looks ok.  I ran it on http://codepad.org/xrWzazER and the results looks as expected.

Comment: I can't see much wrong either.  I expected the usual integer rounding etc, but no...

Comment: Try just '%f' as the format specifier..

Comment: I compiled with GCC and launched it on Debian, I got `The unsorted array is: { 30.000000, 90.000000, 100.000000, 84.000000, 72.000000, 40.000000, 34.000000, 91.000000, 80.000000, 62.000000,}
The mean is: 68.300000
`

Comment: MSVC. The unsorted array is: `{ 30.000000, 90.000000, 100.000000, 84.000000, 72.000000,  40.000000, 34.000000, 91.000000, 80.000000, 62.000000,}`. The mean is: `68.300000`

Comment: To expand on @MartinJames's comment, the standard format to print a `double` value is `%f`. C99 made `%lf` equivalent to `%f`; prior to that, `%lf` had undefined behavior. `%lf` *should* work if you have a correct C implementation (specifically the runtime library), but `%f` is simpler, clearer, and perhaps more likely to work in practice.

Comment: @MartinJames I can't quote it but I was told (in comments) that the `l` in `%lf` is optional for `double`, but I had thought that `%lf` would be used for `long double` (as distinct from `scanf()` formats).

Comment: @WeatherVane: `l` (lower case "ell") is ignored, while `L` is `long double`.http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7 I think this is to make it more similar to `scanf`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed %lf to %f and got the correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to print `mean` with a `%lf` format specifier. That format specifier [isn't valid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), so probably something goes wrong there.

The correct format specifier for `double` would be `%f`, and the `l` length modifier is only allowed for integer formatting. (For floating point there is `L`, making `%Lf` the correct format specifier for `long double`).

Comment: The OP says "codeblocks" but does not specify what *compiler* is used. clang, for example, will output warnings with this construction.

Comment: @Jongware I think the compiler is GNU GCC