# Not working real number in c

Tags: c

I am facing very very strange issue. 
I am writing very simple program in `C`.

Program needs to do: read real number and display it on console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a;
    printf("Give a: ");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("Result for a = %f \n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
sh-4.3$ gcc -o main *.c                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Give a: 123.345                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Result for a = 0.000000
```

http://goo.gl/4j2Bjv

Why there is 0.0000 instead of my number?
Personally I have no idea.... code from this [site](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/code/reading-real-numbers-2569.aspx) is working fine.

Any idea?

Comment: There was an equivalent question recently asked here. There are tons of duplicates here on SO, I think.

Comment: @cad right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269283/scanf-not-reading-in-double#33269387 here, in fact

Comment: ...but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180158/why-is-the-program-printing-0s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%lf` conversion specification to read a `double`, `%f` is for `float`.

Comment: OTOH... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180158/why-is-the-program-printing-0s